# Save textFile dates into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a `file.txt` with this dates:

- "u901_radglobal   ""2019-02-01 00:00""    -7.8047 38.56   5.8193586538461"
- "u901_radglobal   ""2019-02-01 00:01""    -22.641 45.36   14.880951785714"
- "u901_radglobal   ""2019-02-01 00:02""    -8.4229 32.996  8.4629222222222"
- ...

Imagine that is for a only day and from 00:00 to 23:59 soo its abour 1440 columns.
I need to put it into a data base.

My idea is :

- Table sensor : u901_radglobal
- Table day : 2019-02-01
- Table dates: 00:00    -7.8047 38.56 5.8193586538461

Soo sensor has a lot of day and avery day has a lot of dates, but i dont know if this is gonna be correct.
Can u help me?

Comment: Unless you tell us what those dates are and how you're going to use them, it's pretty hard for us to know a correct database structure is.

Comment: Maybe `2019-02-01 00:00` and an id in Table day and then related id and each reading in separate row in table Data.